# What to do when an API has no documentation

Tags: rest, api, powershell, jira

I'm currently trying to use a REST API to insert data from Powershell into a Jira custom field made by a certain plugin (Easy links for JIRA). Unfortunately there's no documentation on the required syntax. Does anyone who's run into this plugin know the commands/syntax I'll need to use the REST API (It's quite a small plugin so I'll be surprised if anyone else has seen it)? Failing that, does anyone have any advice on discovering how to use APIs with no/bad documentation i.e. some standard method of making an API return a list of commands and syntax (preferably by using powershell)?

I've tried contacting the developer but haven't heard back from them.

The code I'm using is here, if that's helpful:

```
function Test-Upload(){
    Param()

        Process{
    $data=@"
    {
    "fields":
    {
        "project":
        {
            "key": "CCWASSET"
        },

        "summary": "Testing Linked Field",
        "issuetype":
        {
            "name": "Asset"
        },
        "description" : "Testing Linked Field"
    },
   "update":{
      "customfield_10500":[
         {
            "set":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"Asset PO",
                  "inward":"Asset",
                  "outward":"Purchase Order"
               },
               "outwardIssue":{
                  "key":""
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
"@
        return Jira-WebRequest -data $data

    }
}


function Jira-WebRequest(){
    Param(
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]$data,
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]$requesttype="issue",
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]$method="POST",
        [Parameter(mandatory=$false)]$ContentType='application/json'
    )
    Process{
        $path = $("/rest/api/2/$requesttype/")
        $Uri = ""
        [URI]::TryCreate([URI]::new($Settings.Jira.URL),"$path",$([ref]$Uri))

        $Params = @{
            ContentType =  $ContentType
            Body = $data #$(@{"vlan_id"=$vlanID;"port_id"="$portID";"port_mode"="$portMode"} | ConvertTo-JSON)
            Method = $method
            URI = $uri.AbsoluteUri
            Headers =  $JiraHeaders
            #WebSession = $Session
        }

        try{
            $result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params -Verbose
            return $result
        } Catch [System.Net.WebException] {
          $exception = $_.Exception
          $respstream = $exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
          $sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $respstream
          $ErrorResult = $sr.ReadToEnd()
          return $ErrorResult
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to check with ferllarom@gmail.com as well. This is the support mail Id I saw from the market place for this plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Prasoon, tried that too but no response

Comment: If it's utilizing PowerShell you can use `Get-Member` if it's not it depends on the language. Usually there might be some form of indicators but it's not as straight forward. Finding documentation, reading the original source or getting support from the author is what works best.

Comment: What is `$JiraHeaders` ? I can't see where that came from

Comment: @Seth `Get-Member` will give members of the object, it can't give the API routes and API methods for the REST endpoint

Comment: Isn't that just the [Jira REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3)?

Comment: @Theo Apologies, $JiraHeaders contains the authorisation info.

Comment: @Ansgar Not quite, it uses the JIRA REST API to connect but it uses its own syntax when setting the actual field value.

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV that's correct but it's also entirely unclear what that Plugin might be utilizing. If you directly interact with the REST API using HTTP(S) you won't get any information that way. If that plugin already contains PowerShell cmdlets you could gain some information that way. Otherwise the other options I pointed out are relevant. For instance there could be a WSDL document available for it in which case you could look at that. The original question just contains very little information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working for this particular plugin. Had to include the ID field as well as the Key of the issue that I want to link to. I'd still be interested to hear if anyone has some tips for working with API's that have no/bad documentation.

```
  "update":{
      "customfield_10500":[
         {
            "set":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"Asset PO",
                  "inward":"Asset",
                  "outward":"Purchase Order"
               },
               "outwardIssue":{
                  "key":""
                  "ID":""
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the custom field made by a plugin or by you. At the end it's custom field so since the plugin doesn't have a good documentation, I would recommend you to stay with Atlassian Documentation and update / edit your issues base on official REST API. You can see Atlassian examples with Custom Fields [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/)

What you need to do is you just need to figure out what's the custom field ID and that would be easy by going towards admin panel and clicking on the custom field and check it from URL if you don't want to go to database.

I know it's pain to see API without documents but at least you can workaround it this way.

Comment: Thanks @Saleh, that's what I've been trying to do. I know the field ID.